# Сколько потоков быстрее заполнит массив?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Дан массив из 10 млн элементов. Хочу понять валидные ли я результаты получил и если нет то где та "золотая середина " между оптимальным количеством потоков и их выполнением.
Собственно вот код:

```
    public class MyArray implements Runnable {
    private static volatile String[] array;
    private final int threadCount;
    private final int elemCount;

    MyArray(int countOfElements, int countOfThreads) {
        array = new String[countOfElements];
        threadCount = countOfThreads;
        this.elemCount = countOfElements;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
                int part = array.length/threadCount;
                for (int index = 0; index < part; index++) {
                    if (index % 3 == 0 && index % 5 == 0) {
                        array[index] = "FizzBuzz";
                        //    System.out.println(array[index]);
                    } else if (index % 5 == 0) {
                        array[index] = "Buzz";
                        //    System.out.println(array[index]);
                    } else if (index % 3 == 0) {
                        array[index] = "Fizz";
                        //    System.out.println(array[index]);
                    } else {
                        array[index] = String.valueOf(index);
                        //    System.out.println(array[index]);
                    }


                }
                //code for calculating method working time
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long workTime = end - start;
            System.out.println(threadCount + " thread(s) fill  of " + array.length + " mln elements array in " + (workTime / 1000.) + " sec");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

и потоки в котором заполняются массивы:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyArray(10_000_000, 1));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new MyArray(10_000_000, 2));
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new MyArray(10_000_000, 5));
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(new MyArray(10_000_000, 10));


        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();


    }

}
```

получается вот такое вот время :

```
5 thread(s) fill  of 10000000 mln elements array in 0.84 sec
1 thread(s) fill  of 10000000 mln elements array in 0.88 sec
10 thread(s) fill  of 10000000 mln elements array in 0.875 sec
2 thread(s) fill  of 10000000 mln elements array in 0.897 sec
```

правильно ли я все сделал и валидные ли результаты?

Comment: юзайте streamApi и не заморачивайтесь...

Comment: @Дмитрий , до стримов я дойду, здесь что я упускаю?)

Comment: я тут вижу только 4 потока (+ главный), никаких 5, 1, 10, 2 потоков, которые заполняют массив тут нет, каждый `run` выполняет один конкретный поток

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сказали в комментах вы создали некорректные условия. Вы в главном треде создаёте 4 треда, которые просто заполняют массив. Вам необходим примерно следующий алгоритм действий:

- Создать в главном треде 4 (если так хотите) треда, по количеству экспериментов.
- В каждом треде в цикле создать ещё ряд тредов, `countOfThreads` единиц.
- Каждом треде из предыдущего пункта заполнять массив.

12 в 4 степень возвожу, чтобы имитировать полезную работу.
Конечный код выглядит примерно так:

```java
class MyArray implements Runnable {
  private int[][] array;
  private final int threadCount;
  private final int elemCount;

  MyArray(int countOfElements, int countOfThreads) {
    array = new int[countOfElements][countOfElements];
    threadCount = countOfThreads;
    this.elemCount = countOfElements;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadCount];
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
      threads[i] = new Thread(new Iter(threadCount, i, elemCount, array));
      threads[i].start();
    }
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
      try {
        thread.join();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long workTime = end - start;
    for (int[] ints : array) {
      for (int anInt : ints) {
        if (anInt != (int)Math.pow(12, 4))
          throw new RuntimeException();
      }
    }
    System.out.println(threadCount + " thread(s) fill  of " +  array[0].length * array[0].length / 1_000_000 +
        " " +
        "mln elements array in " + (workTime / 1000.) + " sec");
  }
}

class Iter implements Runnable {
  private final int step;
  private final int startValue;
  private final int elemCount;
  volatile private int[][] arrToFill;

  public Iter(int step, int startValue, int elemCount, int[][] arrToFill) {
    this.step = step;
    this.startValue = startValue;
    this.elemCount = elemCount;
    this.arrToFill = arrToFill;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      for (int i = startValue; i < elemCount; i += step) {
        for (int j = 0; j < elemCount; j++) {
          arrToFill[i][j] = (int)Math.pow(12, 4);
        }
      }
    } catch(Exception exception){
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
      }
    }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyArray(20000, 1));
    thread1.start();
    thread1.join();
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new MyArray(20000, 2));
    thread2.start();
    thread2.join();
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(new MyArray(20000, 5));
    thread3.start();
    thread3.join();
    Thread thread4 = new Thread(new MyArray(20000, 16));
    thread4.start();
    thread4.join();
  }
}
```

Результат работы такой:

```
1 thread(s) fill  of 400 mln elements array in 7.509 sec
2 thread(s) fill  of 400 mln elements array in 3.841 sec
5 thread(s) fill  of 400 mln elements array in 1.832 sec
16 thread(s) fill  of 400 mln elements array in 1.715 sec
```

Оптимальным считается `количество_ядер х 4 = количество_нитей`. Откуда эти числа взяли не спрашивайте, сам не знаю:) Видел в лекциях Головача на  YouTube.

Comment: да, то что нужно. на*овнокодил я так понимаю знатно, но задачу описал верно. спасибо за помощь в  решении